# How to prevent an outline on SVG path when animating clip path?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this animation to work in my website. For some reason the layered paths show through so a thin white outline for the path (that's animated in) is visible ruining the animation, despite the fact the paths are identical in size. I wondered if anyone has any suggestions on how to prevent this?

I've made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ueq5nf4/) and added the code below. If you change the background for the body to black it's even clearer.

Any help would be appreciate.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 2em;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 8em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#rect {
  animation: slideOver 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slideOver {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}v
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 346">
  <defs>    
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" height="346" width="250"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <path fill="#fff" d="M1.9 0h245.9v58H1.9zM250.1 139.9l-43.8-43.8-81.2 81.2-81.3-81.2L0 139.9l81.2 81.2L0 302.3l43.8 43.9 81.3-81.2 81.2 81.2 43.8-43.9-81.2-81.2"/>
  <path clip-path="url(#clip-path)" fill="#000" d="M1.9 0h245.9v58H1.9zM250.1 139.9l-43.8-43.8-81.2 81.2-81.3-81.2L0 139.9l81.2 81.2L0 302.3l43.8 43.9 81.3-81.2 81.2 81.2 43.8-43.9-81.2-81.2"/>  
</svg>
```